# Does an MD5 have a sufficient hash space to fingerprint files?

Tags: database, hash, md5, entropy, fingerprinting

I'm looking for speedy but not necessarily good hashing.  I know that MD5s can be broken or maliciously crafted, but supposing that I'm not using them for security, and only to insure that a file is the same as when I initially indexed it, is it adequate?

To what extend can I reasonably use MD5 hashing before I will on average have a collision?

I want to store database records as `FILE(id,path,size,md5)`

Should I be able to make md5 unique, or is there not enough entropy for this.  If not and MD5, which hash will scale to the point where I can for all intents and purposes call it unique.  Is a SHA1 adequate even if it's slower.

I have a dataset with N~=50,000,000

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack#Mathematics. Also, really no reason not to use SHA-2 (e.g. 256-bit prefix of SHA-512) instead of MD5. Or a CRC if you want to go the other way.

Comment: @Ry- are you citing
"For comparison, 10^−18 to 10^−15 is the uncorrectable bit error rate of a typical hard disk.[6] In theory, MD5 hashes or UUIDs, being 128 bits, should stay within that range until about 820 billion documents, even if its possible outputs are many more."?

Comment: I was originally pointing to the table, but that quote works too.

Comment: @Ry- So if I've understood correctly you're in the camp that up to a billion records an MD5 is probably just fine, and even then you have entropy up to a considerable amount?  Feel free to post an answer with some clear math and your reasoning,  I"m not entirely clear what the specific problems that MD5 would present are, I only undertand how much entropy the bits will get me.

Comment: Doesn't that table answer your question?

Comment: @JamesKPolk Perhaps, but that's not how stack overflow works, we can't evaluate the quality of an answer unless one is actually posted, and there is consensus.  If there is no one willing to  commit to a "yes that's how it works", how can I trust it.  Stack overflow is about peer review, Wikipedia is peer reviewed, but not necessarily in any way which is structured, or has a memory of "goodness".

Comment: Assuming the votes on an answer represent its quality on Stack Overflow? Dangerous. But again, don’t use MD5.